# In C++, how to convert vector< pair<char, unsigned> > into a string and back again ?

Tags: c++, string, vector

Sorry if the question was already asked before but I am new to C++ and I stuck at below.. .

I have function which returns vector of pair as shown below..

```
    vector< pair<char, unsigned> > freq = create_freq(s); //S is string
```

Now my goal is to convert above vector pair into single string and will pass the same string to another function. 
In that function, again I have to convert back the same string into vector >.

Can someone tell me how to do above two procedures ? I appreciate your help in this one.

Thanks,

Comment: A string is text. What text do you expect from the vector of pairs?

Comment: There is no standard way to do it. The simpliest would be to use std::ostringstream to build the string, then std::istringstream to read it. You decide how the string will be formatted and how to handle invalid input.

Comment: For example, my vector pair is 'c', 17 then I expect to convert that in to 'c-17' and each vector is separated by 'space' or special character

Comment: "how to convert vector< pair<char, unsigned> > into a string and back again" - you write code to do it. There's no pre-made solution.

Answer (score 0):

Code below should do it.  Where `freq` is your instance of `vector<pair<char,unsigned>>`.  You'll likely need to include `#include <sstream>` at the top of your source file.

```
string toString(vector<pair<char, unsigned>> &freq)
{
     ostringstream ss;
     for (auto &p : freq)
     {
         ss << p.first << "-" << p.second;
     }

     return ss.str();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

it is simple code:

```
string unsignedToString(unsigned a){
    string val = "";
    do{
        val = (char)((a%10) + '0') + val;
        a /= 10;
    }while(a > 0);
    return val;
}


string toString(vector < pair < char , unsigned> > vec)
{
    string st = "";
    st += unsignedToString(vec.size());

    for(int i = 0 ; i < vec.size() ; ++i){
        pair < char , unsigned > p = vec[i];
        st += " ";
        st += p.first;
        st += " ";
        st += unsignedToString(p.second);
    }

    return st;

}

vector < pair < char , unsigned> > toVector(string st)
{
    vector < pair < char , unsigned> > vec;
    vec.clear();
    stringstream ss;
    ss.clear();
    ss << st;
    int sz;
    ss >> sz;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < sz ; ++i){
        char ch;
        unsigned ua;
        ss >> ch >> ua;
        vec.push_back(make_pair(ch , ua));
    }

    return vec;
}
```

Comment: The unsignedToString function is unnecessary. Just use a stringstream to append a number to a string.  Also, no need to invoke the "clear" method on the vector and stringstream in the toVector function.  The instances are already "cleared". when they are constructed.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) to build the string and [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) to parse it apart.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// Make the code cleaner. Pick type aliases that make sense to you.
using Freq = std::pair<char, unsigned>;
using FreqVector = std::vector<Freq>;

std::string freq_to_string(const FreqVector &freq)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    for (auto &pr : freq) {
        oss << pr.first << '-' << pr.second << ' ';
    }
    return oss.str();
}

FreqVector string_to_freq(const std::string &str)
{
    FreqVector result;
    std::istringstream iss(str);
    char ch, dash;
    unsigned us;
    while (iss >> ch >> dash >> us) {
        result.emplace_back(ch, us);
    }
    return result;
}
```